# Configure log4j in project

Tags: java, log4j

I have created an `EAR` project where I have implemented log4j.
Now I wanted to externalized the log4j.xml somewhere at classpath of the WAS server which means I want to remove it from my project and place it at WAS server classpath.

In which file I have to configure log4j.xml path? Will it be `application.xml`?

Like in Web project we configure log4j.xml in `web.xml`.

Ex:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/resource/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: is it a JavaEE project or Spring based  - deployed on WAS?

Comment: Its a Spring based project

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the path to your log4j config file by updating the startup script of your server to include in its startup path. 
Like so: `-Dlog4j.configuration=file:<path to log4j.xml>`
Alternatively, you can update WAS's JVM arguments from within the Admin console to include path to your log4j config. It should be somewhere under Servers -> Process Definition -> JVM

Comment: Ok. Let me check and try this.